# Creating editable PDFs from Word documents using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word

We are doing some work with a customer at the moment who would like to be able to put online approximately 500 forms for their customers to download and fill in.  They are currently saved as Microsoft Word documents.
Customers are other businesses who pay a subscription, so they would like to be able to download these forms with their own company branding.  They would like to be able to download these forms as editable PDFs, i.e. the customers can fill in the fields on the PDF before saving their completed copy.
I have seen a number of converters that will create PDFs from HTML, like [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) or [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/), but nothing that will reliably create an editable PDF or that will work with a Word document.

Is anyone aware of a way that will work with a Word document, and dynamically generate PDFs in a mail-merge type scenario that will be fillable and save-able using PHP?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Or, if you can think of a better way to do it, I'm all ears!


**Edit to add more info:**
They wanted to go with PDFs as it will allow people to download a set form that they will not be able to edit, but will still be able to fill in.
The company provide forms for health and safety reasons, for example, an accident report, so the customer will need to fill this in, possibly print it off, and then re-upload it back to the server.

We want to make this as automated as possible, they have approx 500 forms, like I say, and a few hundred customers.  Manual creation of these branded PDFs is not an option!

Comment: A PDF is not editable, it's kinda the point. How are you planning to edit it exactly? Dynamically load it in your website and edit online? Or download and edit it offline?

Comment: PDFs can contain editable forms which people can send back. Don't ask me why Adobe thinks it's a good idea.

Comment: You'd be best off using an external app, like OpenOffice, to handle the word->pdf conversion. Otherwise you're stuck trying to recreate Word's rendering, which basically means recreating Word.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you will have if you use Word Documents or PDFs is that you will basically need the customers to upload the forms manually as PDF and PHP don't easily merge together. I think Google Docs could provide this functionality for you but it would be very difficult to implement from scratch.

In my opinion it would be far easier to generate the forms on a webpage using PHP and then generate a PDF from the user input? This way you could then save the input to the database for future reference which would probably a bit easier in the long term. Generating the forms this way would make customization like the logo quite easy to achieve.

You could then also generate PDFs from the data entered which could then be saved to the server so that they can be accessed at a later date. This may be possible with word documents but i'm not aware of how to do it.

Comment: This would be my preferred route as well, however there are over 500 different forms, and I don't really fancy creating all of those in HTML etc, and I don't think they would be happy paying us to do so

Comment: @Matt Yeah that would take weeks to do that. The only other option that I can suggest is that you allow your customers to search/find the forms that they require. Let them download them and then provide an interface for them to upload the completed forms to the server. You could auto generate PDFs which would include their logo and there are ways of generating PDFs via PHP however including the logo dynamically within a word document seems too difficult and time consuming to even try.

Comment: I am hoping to be able to auto-generate the PDFs using PHP, however I can find plenty of ways to convert HTML to PDF with PHP, but nothing that is generated as a fillable PDF or generated from a Word document.  I think we may have to look at other options for doing this

Comment: @Matt Well I did some research quickly on this and as far as I am aware you can only create a fillable form within a PDF using the commercial adobe products or something similar. Generating this via PHP doesn't seem too easy i'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for that, I kinda guessed that it wasn't going to happen.  Appreciate the help though!